# Firestore Security Rules- enforcing timestamp type when field may be missing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore collection whose documents contain two optional date fields (not all documents contain them). I am not sure how to use the security rules to enforce the fields content type although they may be missing.

1. Currently, these date fields are created with firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate() . I think I can write a statement that looks roughly like this*:

`allow write: if request.resource.data.get("RecordDate", ?) is timestamp;`

but I am not sure what could be the second argument for get() in this case (the "?").

*(based on the documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#enforcing_types_for_optional_fields)

2. I might be changing the method for the creation of these fields to firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(). In that case, how is it possible to use the following rule (or an equivalent), but still allow for missing fields?

`allow write: if request.resource.data.recordDate == request.time;`

Hope the questions are clear enough- pls bear with me, I am a newbe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple or condition like this:

```
if !("RecordDate" in request.resource.data.keys) 
  ||(request.resource.data["RecordDate"] is timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks! To be exact, following your advice I used `(!("recordDate" in request.resource.data.keys()) || (request.resource.data.recordDate is timestamp))` as the get() function requires two arguments, and is no longer needed. But is there any reason not to use get() with timestamps, beside the fact that it is harder to come up with a fake default value (the second argument for get())?

Comment: `request.time` would be a valid timestamp, if that's your preference. I prefer the above as it's a more direct expression of what your rule actually is: you allow a write when either there is no `RecordDate` or it is a valid timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Security Rules cannot modify or change the values requested, you can only allow or deny a request. If you want to ensure a certain field is of a timestamp, you can only compare it to the valid types that are listed in the reference documentation:

[Firestore Security Rules: Types - Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp)

To allow for missing fields you can use an OR operator `||` and wrap conditions inside `()` to group their logic together.

```js
request.auth.uid != null || (resource.data.visibility == 'public' && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure I understand it. Why is the timestamp case any different from other value types as to the use of the get() function? In a string case, for example, the documentation gives the following example as a solution for an optional field: `docData.get("photo_url", " '') is string` . The second argument, if I underdtand correctly, is a default argument only for the sake of checking(it does not get into the database). In that case, what could be a default timestamp value?

Comment: gotcha. for a default timestamp, you can use the Security Rules equivalent of Date.now() which is `request.time` and can be used for example: `request.time.date() < resource.data.date` - this timestamp also supports nano second accuracy.